# Android NDK cmake JNI static library

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, java-native-interface

Because of security concerns I would like to link all libraries statically including my native library containing JNI_OnLoad function. I've read that it's possible to link JNI library statically (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#library_version) but I fail to do it with Android Studio. Is it possible?

Here's what I have currently.

In Java code:

```
System.loadLibrary("testlibrary");
```

In cmake makefile:

```
add_library( testlibrary
         STATIC
         ${mysources} )
target_link_libraries(testlibrary)
```

In C++ file:

```
extern "C" {
EXPORT
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad_testlibrary(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
   ...
   return JNI_VERSION_1_8;
}
```

When built with Android Studio application fails because it tries to find *.so library file:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/xxx-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libtestlibrary.so"

Comment: `target_link_libraries` accepts at least 2 arguments: executable/library and other library to link with it. In your code you pass only one argument.

Comment: What security concerns are you attempting to solve by using a static library instead of a dynamic one? Static libraries, if anything, contain more information than a shared one, not less.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid cases when someone decides to override functions inside shared libraries with fake ones from custom library.

Comment: Tsyvarev, I think additional parameters are optional. In reality I have list of additional libraries following 1st paramter, but that is not relevant for my question)

Answer (score 1):

```
System.loadLibrary("testlibrary");
```

This line tries to load `libtestlibrary.so`, and obviously it wasn't built and packed into APK, since library with this name is static one:

```
add_library( testlibrary
         STATIC
         ${mysources} )
```

Here you've described target `libtestlibrary.a`, that is not loadable, and can only be linked against loadable `.so`. So to achieve desired result you should declare `testlibrary` as shared one, and then link it against another static libraries. As result you'll get one, monolitic shared library, that can be loaded into program address space. E.g

```
add_library(testlibrary SHARED ${mysources})
add_library(lib1 STATIC ${lib1_src})
add_library(lib2 STATIC ${lib2_src})
...
target_link_libraries(testlibrary lib1 lib2 ...)
```

Comment: That's what i have currently - shared library linking multiple static libraries. But that's not what I wanted. I thought there could be a way to place all native code inside static library avoiding shared one. As suggested in link I provided:
    `If a library L is statically linked, then upon the first invocation of System.loadLibrary("L") or equivalent API, a JNI_OnLoad_L function will be invoked with the same arguments and expected return value as specified for the JNI_OnLoad function.`

Comment: @jozols Seems like this quote is about feature that is not supported by Android at the moment.  Only shared libraries are meaningful in APK and may be recognized by Android runtime.

Comment: it needs to be shared lib to be loaded, like dll on windows.

Comment: Java 8 does add static linking to JNI. But this works when Java VM is loaded from a C executable which is linked with this static library. In Android, tis would mean that you need a custom zygote linked with your static lib.